# Android: get id of dynamically created button

Tags: android

I have 10 buttons created at runtime. How can I get the id of them?

```
private void buttons() {
    int count = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        Button newButton = new Button(this);
        newButton.setId("button_" + i);
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll.addView(newButton,lp);
    }

}
```

what i need to do is...

```
button_1.getX();
```

Comment: Althought your question is not clear enough, it seems pretty clear you didn't even try to search for an already existing answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not well formed. I assume you don't want to get id itself, but instead you want to have access to that `Button` which name you don't know. So basically you cannot achieve this with `id`. You completely misunderstood concept of `id` in `View` - it's just a field in `View` object, which can be used by you to identify your specific object, but you can't use it as a field name, thus 1.getX() (where `1` is a button's id) is not possible.

What you want is to create (instead of creating a bunch of `Button`s called b1, b2, b3, b4, etc.) an array of `Button`s and access them with indexes:

```
private void buttons() {
    int count = 10;

    Button [] buttons = new Button[count];

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        buttons[i] = new Button(this);
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll.addView(buttons[i],lp);
    }

}
```

Then you have access to specific button as simple, as accessing object at specific position in an array:

```
buttons[id].getX()
```

I have created this array inside your function, but of course if you want to have access to it from outside the function, you may want to declare it for example as a field of your class.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Sorry, english is not my native language.

Comment: It's not about English, it's just you didn't really understand what you wanted to achieve, but that's ok. We managed to find it out. :-)

Comment: Thanks man! :D Works like Charm, Pls Add `buttons[i].setId(i)` would be much more better to identify the button later if you wish :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you set the IDs of your dynamically created buttons, they wouldn't have a specific ids. So, while you are creating those buttons, set some id by saying

```
button.setId(something)
```

and then

```
button.getId()
```

Answer (score 0):

use the [getId](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId%28%29)() method of the view:

```
button_1.getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the instance of the button. Do not you the ids when creating controls in code.

For example:

```
Map<Integer, Button> buttons = new HashMap<Integer, Button>()

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        Button newButton = new Button(this);
    buttons.add(i, newButton);
    ...
}
```

Comment: good one although an array is sufficient

Comment: Depends on the use case. If you need a reference to a specific button then you need some kind of key. When you don't need the reference then the list/array is not needed at all.

Comment: I think after all, it is not a REAL QUESTION :p